# Как на чистом javascript-e вставить тег в начало HTML странички?

Tags: html, javascript

Имеется HTML страничка, которая уже сформирована (к ней подключены javascript-ы). Нужно вставить т.н. "тип текущего документа", а именно строку

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

в самое начало HTML. Вставить нужно, добавив функцию или событие в один из подключаемых скриптов **без использования дополнительных библиотек типа jQuery.** Что-то типа такого:

```
document.insertBefore(document.createElement('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'), document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0]);
```

Comment: Интересно, для чего это понадобилось?

Comment: Судя по всему, для проблемы "имеется 100500 html файликов". Я угадал? =)

Comment: Типа того))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У яваскрипта есть только read-only доступ к доктайпу. да и бесполезно это: на момент срабатывания яваскрипта браузер для себя уже все давно решил, что это за доктайп и как его отображать.

А еще у вас ошибка в функции createElement. Она принимает в качестве параметра не HTML, а название тэга.